# SQL - count value breaks in a column when specifying break parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

This builds on a previous question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740645/how-to-count-number-of-non-consecutive-values-in-a-column-using-sql).

I have a table which tracks service involvement (srvc_invl) for two individuals (name) over a period of time (day).

```
name  day  srvc_inv
Liam  1  1
Liam  2  0
Liam  3  1
Liam  4  0
Liam  5  0 
Liam  6  1
Liam  7  0
Noel  1  0
Noel  2  0
Noel  3  1
Noel  4  0
Noel  5  1
Noel  6  1
Noel  7  1
```

My goal is to count the number of unique service involvements per individual. Previously, we accomplished this by counting breaks in service involvement 1's and 0's using a lag function:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(srvc_inv, 1, 0) over (partition by name order by day) as prev_srvc_inv
      from t
     ) t
where prev_srvc_inv = 0 and srvc_inv = 1
group by name;
```

However, I have just found out that breaks in service involvement can be defined differently based on the program of interest. I.e. for some programs, one-day of non-consecutive service counts as a break, for example:

```
day  srvc_inv
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

= 2 service episodes

but for other programs, two or more days of non-consecutive service counts as a break, for example:

```
day  srvc_inv
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

= 1 service episode, but

```
day  srvc_inv
1  1
2  0
3  0
4  1
5  0
```

= 2 service episodes

Using the table at the top of this post, let us assume we are analyzing a program that considers **two days of non-consecutive service involvement** to be a service break and thus a distinct service episode.

How would I modify the above query, or write a new query, that would allow me to specify the break number parameters?

My desired output is as follows:

```
name  srvc_episodes
Liam  2
Noel  1
```

Thank you so so so much for any help anyone can offer on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a running sum rather than `lag()`.  This gives you more flexibility:

```
select name, count(*) 
from (select t.*,
             sum(srvc_inc) over (partition by name
                                 order by day
                                 rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding
                                ) as sum_srvc_inc_2
      from t
     ) t
where (sum_srvc_inc_2 = 0 or sum_srvc_inc_2 is null) and srvc_inc = 1
group by name;
```

You would adjust the "2"s for the length of time for the split.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks again for the help! Quick question - where am I creating sum_srvc_inc in the WHERE statement? i can't find that defined anywhere in the query

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out. Was meant to be sum_srvc_inc_2 is null. You are a legend Gordon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME, 
SUM(CASE WHEN SRVC_INV = 1
AND (LAG1 = 1 OR LAG2 = 1 OR (LAG1 IS NULL AND LAG2 IS NULL)) 
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS SERVICE_EPISODES
FROM
(SELECT NAME, SRVC_INV,
LAG(SRVC_INV,1) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY DAY) AS LAG1,
LAG(SRVC_INV,2) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY DAY) AS LAG2
FROM T)
GROUP BY NAME
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Tejash - I ended up using Gordon's answer above as it allows for changing parameters via a single number transformation. Appreciate you writing this up too :)

Comment: Yes, I also learned it from @gordon. He is a genius freak. Haha